# I do not want a child to inherit parent's css

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project built up like this:

- index page with full layout
- separate php files including the index page

In the index page I use bootstrap but in the separate php files I sometimes use jqgrid, which does not go along with bootstrap all too well. The combination of these two makes jqgrid's shrinktofit or autowidth disfunction.

Is there any way to exclude the whole bootstrap css from being inherited in my separate php files?

Comment: Don't include the CSS file?

Comment: Probably, but you will have to show some code. "separate php files including the index page" is not clear - do you mean phps `include "index.php";`

Comment: Yes I do it by using phps include function. The index file imports all css files for both jqgrid and bootstrap, so I don't have to include it every time in each php file

Comment: So you want some elements on the page to use bootstrap's classes, but other's not to?  That's more difficult than just not including bootstrap...

Comment: I just want child elements not to inherit the parent's bootstrap css

Answer (score 1):

yes you can exclude whole bootstrap functionality , by using php regular expression to comment the link to the bootstrap file loading, so that the bootstrap functionality will not affect the page.

Comment: Not sure how I would do this though!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (__FILE__ == "index.php") {
  echo  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
}
```

Comment: syntax of echo doesn't seem to allow this